# How do you cause Spring to inject into/call setters of a Spring annotated class?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

is there a way to add annotations to the class below to specify to Spring to inject into the instances a bean for bar?

```
@Scope("prototype")
@Component("vnetwork-start")
//how to inject bar value?
public class VNetworkStartCommand extends VNetworkCommand { 
    public VNetworkStartCommand() { super(VNetworkCommandType.START); }

    @Required public void setBar(Bar bar) { System.out.println("bar="+bar); }   
}
```

Comment: You can use `@Autowired`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate the method with Spring's `@Autowired`, or `javax.inject`'s `@Inject`, or `javax.annotation`'s `@Resource`.

This obviously assumes that annotation configuration is enabled and a `Bar` bean is available in the context.